# No new wallpapers in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ipad, wallpaper

I don't know, maybe I'm missing something. I have upgraded my iPad Mini 2 from iOS 9 to iOS 10. Official release, not a beta, neither a GM.  I don't see any new wallpaper.

Are there any new wallpapers included in iOS 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one new wallpaper included in iOS 10, shown below. iOS 9.1 included new wallpapers so it's possible that 10.1 will as well.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I would assume apple isnt focusing on wallpapers so if you dont see any dont be alarmed since not everyone is looking for wallpapers in new updates and new wall papers might come out in future partial updates.

Comment: This answer is speculation at best, and doesn't address the question of whether any new wallpapers were included with iOS 10.